# What is the best convention to generate multiple payload for different endpoints in python code?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, payload

My project requires different request payload for different endpoints. I am generating each one of them in python code and pass the generated payload to the python requests library. It's working but I am looking for a more elegant/cleaner way to do it. I was thinking about having yaml files and read them to generate my payload. Looking for more ideas and better way to generate request payload.

```
def abc(self):
    payload = {
             'key1' :'1',
             'key2' : '2'
               }
     return payload

def call_abc(self):
    request_payload = self.abc()
    requests.post(url, json=request_payload, headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you use YAML or JSON. Look at this code:

```py
request_map = {
    "http://some/end/point": [
        {
            'key1': '1',
            'key2': '2'
        },
        {
            'key3': '4',
            'key4': '5'
        }
    ],
    "http://some/other/end/point": [
        {
            'key1': '1',
            'key2': '2'
        },
        {
            'key3': '4',
            'key4': '5'
        }
    ]
}

def generate_call():
    for endpoint, payloads in request_map.items():
        for payload in payloads:
            yield endpoint, payload


def call_endpoint(url, payload):
    requests.post(url, data=payload)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for url, payload in generate_call():
        call_endpoint(url, payload)
```

this will generate 4 calls like this:

```py
http://some/end/point {'key1': '1', 'key2': '2'}
http://some/end/point {'key3': '4', 'key4': '5'}
http://some/other/end/point {'key1': '1', 'key2': '2'}
http://some/other/end/point {'key3': '4', 'key4': '5'}
```

and if you want to use put them in a yaml or json file and load it in the `request_map` variable. You don't need do any other operation on them. 
like:

```py
request_map = yaml.safe_load(open('request_map.yaml'))
```

or:

```py
request_map = json.load(open('request_map.json'))
```